# Reversing vertical scrolling

Tags: python, pygame

I have taken the sourcecode for scrolling from this website
https://coderslegacy.com/python/pygame-scrolling-background/

unfortunately it scrolls up instead of down. I would like to reverse the scrolling. This is the relevant code:

```
class Background():
      def __init__(self):
            self.bgimage = pygame.image.load('AnimatedStreet.png')
            self.rectBGimg = self.bgimage.get_rect()
 
            self.bgY1 = 0
            self.bgX1 = 0
 
            self.bgY2 = self.rectBGimg.height
            self.bgX2 = 0
 
            self.moving_speed = 5
         
      def update(self):
        self.bgY1 -= self.moving_speed
        self.bgY2 -= self.moving_speed
        if self.bgY1 <= -self.rectBGimg.height:
            self.bgY1 = self.rectBGimg.height
        if self.bgY2 <= -self.rectBGimg.height:
            self.bgY2 = self.rectBGimg.height
             
      def render(self):
         DISPLAYSURF.blit(self.bgimage, (self.bgX1, self.bgY1))
         DISPLAYSURF.blit(self.bgimage, (self.bgX2, self.bgY2))
```

Inverting the moving speed only shows weird artifacts and i do not understand it enough.

Comment: I don't believe anyone will be able to answer the question without more information about your program. How is this called? What does your loop look like? Could you provide a minimum reproducible example?

Comment: @Starbuck5 Sorry, but the issue is obvious. No further information is required.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Thanks for the catch @Rabbid76

Comment: I did include a link to the complete source. Is easily missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the moving speed to the y-coordinate instead of subtracting it:

<s>`self.bgY1 -= self.moving_speed`</s>
<s>`self.bgY2 -= self.moving_speed`</s>

```py
self.bgY1 += self.moving_speed
self.bgY2 += self.moving_speed
```

In addition, you can simplify the code. Use the modulo (`%`) operator to compute the y-coordinate:

```py
class Background():
    def __init__(self):
        self.bgimage = pygame.image.load('AnimatedStreet.png')
        self.rectBGimg = self.bgimage.get_rect()
        self.bgY = 0
        self.bgX = 0
        self.moving_speed = 5
        
    def update(self):
        self.bgY = (self.bgY + self.moving_speed) % self.rectBGimg.height
                
    def render(self):
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(self.bgimage, (self.bgX, self.bgY - self.rectBGimg.height))
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(self.bgimage, (self.bgX, self.bgY))
```